# Solving transcendental equation in matlab

Tags: matlab, intersection, trigonometry, numerical-integration, transcendental-equation

Looking for help solving transcendental equations in Matlab. 
Here's an equation for example:

1/2 = cos(x)cos(2x) ; 0<=x<=pi/2
solving for x:

x = acos((1/2)(sec(2x))

I have tried using intersect() along with various other Matlab functions. It's easy to see an approximate value of ~.48 when I plot using the following code:

```
x = 0:(pi/2)/1000:pi/2;
f = @(x) (1/2)*acos((1/2)*sec(x));
plot(x,f(x));
```

How can I have Matlab return the value where x == f(x) within a certain tolerance?

Comment: Your problem is equivalent to `cos(x)=z` for `z` any of the solutions of `0.5=2*z^3-z` so that you have a polynomial roots problem and a trigonometric inversion,both relatively easy.

Answer (score 1):

For finding a numerical solution it doesn't really matter if you have a polynomial or even a transcendental equation. In general for your particular problem there are two nice built-ins: `fzero` tries to find a root of a function `f`, that is a value `x` where `f(x) == 0`. You need to provide an initial estimate but you cannot provide bounds. Then there is `fminbnd` which *minimizes* your function, so you have to write your problem as a *minimization problem*. But in this case you can provide bounds:

```matlab
format long
% find a root (unbounded)
f=@(x)1/2 - cos(x).*cos(2*x);
z = fzero(f,0,optimset('TolX',1e-5));
disp(z);

% find a minimum (bounded)
g=@(x)(f(x)).^2;
z = fminbnd(g,0,pi/2,optimset('TolX',1e-5));
disp(z);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY29CsIwFIX3PsVdpDelPzbgJAUfwsFJSJukBJrc0iZS@vIxiujocs4ZPs5HgxcPFaOmxQoPE7kxO4A2ToKAhcgDBtdTcFJJlunughtrGw4VDLSmXRev5sXGztkOHehdLYS6PJY0e2NX5TG/0nTLy1ZVJ5YoadYZ9zR@HmucscECfkXjW4Q6Bavv/POduN5JHNP7bBr@VxHjEw)